# Python: How to round numbers smaller than 1 adaptively with specified precision?

Tags: python, numpy

I usually use

```
x = round(x, 3)
```

to round a number to the precision of 3 digits. Now I have this array:

```
[-1.10882605e-04 -2.01874994e-05  3.24209095e-05 -1.56917988e-05
 -4.61406358e-05  1.99080610e-05  7.04079594e-05  2.64600122e-05
 -3.53022316e-05  1.50542793e-05]
```

And using the same code just flattens everything down to 0. What I would like to have though is a function that gives me the most significant 3 digits rounded like it usually works for numbers larger than 1. Like this:

```
special_round(0.00034567, 3)
=
0.000346
```

Any idea how this could be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that figures out the order of magnitude and does an elment wise rounding.

Note that this will only work correctly for values < 1 and > -1, which I guess is a valid assumption regarding your example data.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-1.10882605e-04, -2.01874994e-05,  3.24209095e-05, -1.56917988e-05,
 -4.61406358e-05,  1.99080610e-05,  7.04079594e-05 , 2.64600122e-05,
 -3.53022316e-05 , 1.50542793e-05])

def special_round(vec):
  exponents = np.floor(np.log10(np.abs(vec))).astype(int)
  return np.stack([np.round(v, decimals=-e+3) for v, e in zip(vec, exponents)])

b = special_round(a)
>>> array([-1.109e-04, -2.019e-05,  3.242e-05, -1.569e-05, -4.614e-05,
        1.991e-05,  7.041e-05,  2.646e-05, -3.530e-05,  1.505e-05])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you elaborate a bit on what `special_round` does here? I'm relatively new to NumPy and don't get what it does.

Comment: the variable `exponents` basically contains the powers of 10 per entry that are also displayed in the example data `a`. This can be done by calculating the logarithm with basis 10 (`np.log10`) and then round to the next smaller integer (`np.floor`). Then the rounding function is applied to every element in the input vector using the corresponding decimal (exponent+1), using a list comprehension. afterwards it is stacked to a `np.array` again. \

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, numbers you provided are starting to be so small that you are approaching limit of floating point precision, thus some artifacts show up seemingly for no reason.

```
def special_round(number, precision):
    negative = number < 0
    number = abs(number)
    i = 0
    while number <= 1 or number >= 10:
        if number <= 1:
            i += 1
            number *= 10
        else:
            i += -1
            number /= 10
    rounded = round(number, precision)
    if negative:
        rounded = -rounded
    return rounded * (10 ** -i)
```

Output:

```
[-0.0001109, -2.019e-05, 3.2420000000000005e-05, -1.569e-05, -4.614e-05, 1.9910000000000004e-05, 7.041000000000001e-05, 2.646e-05, -3.5300000000000004e-05, 1.505e-05]
```

Comment: Your answer is the only one I understand directly. So you scale the number up until it is bigger than 1, use regular round and then scale it down again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by creating a specific function using the `math` package:

```
from math import log10 , floor
import numpy as np


def round_it(x, sig):
    return round(x, sig-int(floor(log10(abs(x))))-1)

a = np.array([-1.10882605e-04, -2.01874994e-05,  3.24209095e-05, -1.56917988e-05,
              -4.61406358e-05,  1.99080610e-05,  7.04079594e-05,  2.64600122e-05,
              -3.53022316e-05,  1.50542793e-05])
round_it_np = np.vectorize(round_it)  # vectorize the function to apply on numpy array
round_it_np(a, 3)  # 3 is rounding with 3 significant digits
```

This will result in

```
array([-1.11e-04, -2.02e-05,  3.24e-05, -1.57e-05, -4.61e-05,  1.99e-05,
    7.04e-05,  2.65e-05, -3.53e-05,  1.51e-05])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you explain a bit how `round_it` does what it does? I find it hard to understand.

Comment: The first part `log10(abs(x))` will compute what power you should apply to 10 to get the number `x`. So for instance for -1.10882605e-04 this will result into -3.955136579595221 (i.e. -1.10882605e-04 = 10**-3.955136579595221). By taking the floor you will round it to the next lowest integer (in this case -4) so it means that the first significant digit is at position -4 (so first 3 zeroes and then the 1). So if you want 3 significant digits you need to round up to 7 digits (3 - -4).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```py
from math import log10, ceil

def special_round(x, n) :
    lx = log10(abs(x))
    if lx >= 0 : return round(x, n)
    return round(x, n-ceil(lx))

for x in [10.23456, 1.23456, 0.23456, 0.023456, 0.0023456] :
    print (x, special_round(x, 3))
    print (-x, special_round(-x, 3))
```

Output:

```
10.23456 10.235
-10.23456 -10.235
1.23456 1.235
-1.23456 -1.235
0.23456 0.235
-0.23456 -0.235
0.023456 0.0235
-0.023456 -0.0235
0.0023456 0.00235
-0.0023456 -0.00235
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the common logarithm (provided by the built-in math module) to calculate the position of the first significant digit in your number (with 2 representing the hundreds, 1 representing the tens, 0 representing the ones, -1 representing the 0.x, -2 representing the 0.0x and so on...). Knowing the position of the first significant digit, you can use it to properly round the number.

```
import math

def special_round(n, significant_digits=0):
    first_significant_digit = math.ceil((math.log10(abs(n))))
    round_digits = significant_digits - first_significant_digit
    return round(n, round_digits)

>>> special_round(0.00034567, 3)
>>> 0.000346
```